# Netty SslHandler headache

Tags: scala, netty

I've wasted a couple of days now trying to track down an intermittent bug in the newly added Akka transport encryption.

NOTE: I have experimented with setting setIssueHandshake(true) on either or both of the server and the clients, but it doesn't help at all.

Our cipher spec tests a couple of different ciphers from different suites, to make sure that the settings we support actually works. However, the tests can sometimes pass 10 times, and then start failing every other test, it's truly *SecureRandomly* failing ;-)
Please do note that the test fails even on SHA1PRNG so it is clearly unrelated to the additional ciphers we provide.

The code that creates the SslHandler: https://github.com/akka/akka/blob/wip-ssl-unbroken-%E2%88%9A/akka-remote/src/main/scala/akka/remote/netty/NettySSLSupport.scala

The code that constructs the pipeline: https://github.com/akka/akka/blob/wip-ssl-unbroken-%E2%88%9A/akka-remote/src/main/scala/akka/remote/netty/NettyRemoteSupport.scala#L66

The tests: https://github.com/akka/akka/blob/wip-ssl-unbroken-%E2%88%9A/akka-remote/src/test/scala/akka/remote/Ticket1978CommunicationSpec.scala

The fall-back config (for what the test above doesn't override): https://github.com/akka/akka/blob/wip-ssl-unbroken-%E2%88%9A/akka-remote/src/main/resources/reference.conf

The keystore & truststore to use for the test: https://github.com/akka/akka/tree/wip-ssl-unbroken-%E2%88%9A/akka-remote/src/test/resources

The root exception that fails the test is:

```
**java.security.InvalidKeyException: No installed provider supports this key: (null)**
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.a(DashoA13*..)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.init(DashoA13*..)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.init(DashoA13*..)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.CipherBox.<init>(CipherBox.java:88)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.CipherBox.newCipherBox(CipherBox.java:119)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.CipherSuite$BulkCipher.newCipher(CipherSuite.java:369)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Handshaker.newReadCipher(Handshaker.java:410)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.changeReadCiphers(SSLEngineImpl.java:550)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.readRecord(SSLEngineImpl.java:1051)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.readNetRecord(SSLEngineImpl.java:845)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.unwrap(SSLEngineImpl.java:721)
    at javax.net.ssl.SSLEngine.unwrap(SSLEngine.java:607)
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.unwrap(SslHandler.java:969)
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decode(SslHandler.java:670)
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.frame.FrameDecoder.callDecode(FrameDecoder.java:333)
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.frame.FrameDecoder.messageReceived(FrameDecoder.java:214)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:268)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:255)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.read(NioWorker.java:91)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.processSelectedKeys(AbstractNioWorker.java:373)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.run(AbstractNioWorker.java:247)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.run(NioWorker.java:35)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
```

And the "full" one is:

```
[ERROR] [06/20/2012 10:38:33.670] [remote-sys-4] [ActorSystem(remote-sys)] RemoteServerError@akka://remote-sys@localhost:59104] Error[
javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Algorithm missing:  
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.changeReadCiphers(SSLEngineImpl.java:554)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.readRecord(SSLEngineImpl.java:1051)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.readNetRecord(SSLEngineImpl.java:845)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.unwrap(SSLEngineImpl.java:721)
    at javax.net.ssl.SSLEngine.unwrap(SSLEngine.java:607)
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.unwrap(SslHandler.java:969)
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decode(SslHandler.java:670)
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.frame.FrameDecoder.callDecode(FrameDecoder.java:333)
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.frame.FrameDecoder.messageReceived(FrameDecoder.java:214)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:268)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:255)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.read(NioWorker.java:91)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.processSelectedKeys(AbstractNioWorker.java:373)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.run(AbstractNioWorker.java:247)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.run(NioWorker.java:35)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
Caused by: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Could not create cipher AES/128
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.CipherBox.<init>(CipherBox.java:99)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.CipherBox.newCipherBox(CipherBox.java:119)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.CipherSuite$BulkCipher.newCipher(CipherSuite.java:369)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Handshaker.newReadCipher(Handshaker.java:410)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.changeReadCiphers(SSLEngineImpl.java:550)
    ... 17 more
Caused by: java.security.InvalidKeyException: No installed provider supports this key: (null)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.a(DashoA13*..)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.init(DashoA13*..)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.init(DashoA13*..)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.CipherBox.<init>(CipherBox.java:88)
    ... 21 more
]
```

Answer (score 3):

Not a bug in Netty, there was an unfortunate write-race between the application-level handshake and the SSL handshake. Worth to note is that setIssueHandshake(true) doesn't seem to be transparently handling the handshake as you need to manually back off writes until the handshake is completed.

Comment: I think this was fixed in netty 3.5.0.Final.. what version you are using?

Comment: can you please open a bug so we can fix it before 3.5.1Final?

Comment: A bug for setIssueHandshake? Because other than that of course I needed to wait for the handshake Future to complete before issuing the application level handshake.

Comment: yeah I wonder if we just should queue messages until the handshake is complete.. on the other side we may just make it more clear from the javadocs how it works.

Comment: Intuitively I'd say it should establish the handshake before letting any messages through. Otherwise what's the point of it?

Comment: It should probably also be enabled by default as it's non-intuitive to have to handle the handshake manually.

Comment: In 4.x its enabled by default

Comment: Excellent. How about not cascading connectionOpened etc until handshake is done?

Comment: Essentially treat it as two pipelines, the first one being the SSL handshake and you don't pipe things to the second pipeline unless the first pipeline has been set up i.e. handshake is completed.

Answer (score 2):

whilst I've not seen exactly this exception, it's certainly the case that a `javax.crypto.Cipher` is not thread safe; I have an application where I finally tracked down a bug which was solved by synchronizing on the cipher:

```
cipher synchronized { cipher doFinal encryptedBytes }
```

Apologies if this is not the solution, but you posted a lot of code! (It's probably not exactly the same as the stack trace indicates that the issue is even getting a `Cipher` instance - but could this also need synchronizing?)